# Group Cohomology for Reductive Groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Can anyone provide a reference to proofs of statements of the following type:  The higher algebric group cohomology of a reductive group $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$ vanishes.

I am interested not just in finite dimensional modules but also "rational representations" for instance the functions on a vector space $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ on which $G$ acts.

Comment: I'd second BCnrd's request for a clearer formulation.   As far as I know, the deep cohomology questions center either on real/complex Lie groups and infinite dimensional representations, or on reductive algebraic groups in prime characteristic (where interesting representations are usually finite dimensional but complete reducibility usually fails).   

Comment: @Jim:  Maybe it wasn't meant as a deep question; maybe Brian simply answered it?

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  The question may indeed have just been trivial in light of BCnrd's observation.

Comment: @BCnrd: I suggest reposting your comment as the answer to the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rational representations are directed unions of finite-dimensional ones, on which all linear representations of $G$ are completely reducible (either by an ad hoc definition of "reductive group" or a theorem applied to a good definition). So the functor of $G$-invariants on the category of rational representations is exact, hence one gets the desired higher vanishing (by whatever reasonable method one chooses to define the higher cohomologies).

Comment: It's probably helpful to add a reference, though people studying infinite dimensional representations of reductive groups in characteristic 0 tend to focus on Lie groups.   So I'm not sure what a "standard" reference would be, though Hochschild's books get into the interface with algebraic groups.  Even though Jantzen's book *Representations of Algebraic Groups* is aimed mainly at prime characteristic, much of the foundational material he covers at first is in the spirit of this question. 